# How to evaluate xsl:if for numbers?

Tags: xml, xslt

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LV9

`<person age="18"/>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>


    <xsl:template match="person">
      <xsl:variable name="given" select="12" />

      <xs:if test="(@age &lt; $given)">
          <xsl:value-of select="(@age &lt; $given)"/>
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:text>SHOULD NOT PRING</xsl:text>
      </xs:if>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
false
SHOULD NOT PRING
```

Why on earth does it print, when the condition obviously evaluates to `false`?

Comment: It's confusing that in your post you remove the namespace declaration for the `xs:` prefix - which should throw an error. In your XSLT fiddle you do have this namespace.

Comment: Just a copy paste type, corrected it. Still, the answer below is correct: using `xsl` tag instead solves it.

Comment: Thanks! Just making sure that the question is self-contained. Yes, the answer is correct. `xs:if` is not an XSLT instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
xs:if
```

to:

```
xsl:if
```

What you have now is not a condition, but a literal result element. You can see this if you change the output method to `xml`.

---

P.S. Not sure why you need the parentheses.